# Step by step instructions on how to use Obfuscar

Tags: .net, obfuscar

I've installed Obfuscar 2.2.4 through the package manager but I haven't got a clue what to do next. I'm using Visual studio community 2015. I'd like to try out Obfuscar on a VB.NET dll I've written. Simple step by step instructions would be great.

Comment: http://docs.obfuscar.com/en/latest/tutorials/basics.html You can follow the basic example.